# Reading Package List Error Xenial

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 16.04

After upgrading to ubuntu 16.04, whenever I run `sudo apt update`, I receive **Reading Package List Error** and for most of the archives, **Failed to fetch  http://. . .  Empty files can't be valid archives**.
Following the suggestion on Ubuntu forum when I issue the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

things get back on track.

However after a few days I encounter the same problem again. How can I resolve this issue?